# Python tkinter scrollbar: is it possible to set the number of pixels to be shifted by clicking arrow1 or arrow2?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar

I'm using a class ScrollbarFrame(tk.Frame) to display a table and want the table to be shifted by 1 row, clicking the up button (arrow1) or the down button (arrow2). Each row has a height of 21 pixels. Currently the shift is ca. 28 pixels.

What I found is, that each click on an arrow button scrolls 1 unit.  However, I haven't found any settings for unit or any other setting for changing the scroll length.
Thank you for your help!

Here is my class:

```
class ScrollbarFrame(tk.Frame):
"""
Extends class tk.Frame to support a scrollable Frame 
This class is independent from the widgets to be scrolled and 
can be used to replace a standard tk.Frame
"""
def __init__(self, parent, width=0, height=0, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, **kwargs)

    # The Scrollbar, layout to the right
    vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical")
    vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")

    # The Canvas which supports the Scrollbar Interface, layout to the left
    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
    self.canvas.configure(width=width, height=height)

    self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

    # Bind the Scrollbar to the self.canvas Scrollbar Interface
    self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
    vsb.configure(command=self.canvas.yview)

    # The Frame to be scrolled, layout into the canvas
    # All widgets to be scrolled have to use this Frame as parent
    self.scrolled_frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background=self.canvas.cget('bg'))
    
    self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.scrolled_frame, anchor="nw")

    # Configures the scrollregion of the Canvas dynamically
    self.scrolled_frame.bind("<Configure>", self.on_configure)

def on_configure(self, event):
    """Set the scroll region to encompass the scrolled frame"""
    self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))
```

Comment: Ultimately, are you trying to scroll a canvas? I don't know what a `ScrollbarFrame` is, since that's not part of tkinter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `ScrollbarFrame` uses a canvas in order to scroll the frame, you can set the unit size on the canvas with the `yscrollincrement` option.